# How do I get some lines from TXT file with CMD (Only Windows Command Line)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, find

I want to check the status of the USB scan device connected to the remote computer using the Windows command line, `cmd.exe`. (I only use Canon and Fijutsu brand scanners)

The command I use: `pnputil /enum-devices > control.txt`

I search for `Canon  Fijutsu` in TXT and find it, but the device status remains in the online/offline sub-lines. How can I filter them?

Sample TXT file:

```
Instance ID: ACPI\PNP0100\4&12567db6&0
Device Description: System timer
Class Name: System
Class GUID: {4d36e97d-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Manufacturer Name: (Standard system devices)
Status: Stopped
Driver Name: machine.inf

Instance ID: USB\VID_1083&PID_1661\5&886c6fc&0&2
Device Description: CANON DR-C240 USB
Class Name: Image
Class GUID: {6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}
Manufacturer Name: CANON
Status: Started
Driver Name: oem3.inf

Instance ID: ACPI\HPQ8002\4&12567db6&0
Device Description: Standard PS/2 Keyboard
Class Name: Keyboard
Class GUID: {4d36e96b-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Manufacturer Name: (Standard keyboards)
Status: Problem
Problem Code: 24 (0x18) [CM_PROB_DEVICE_NOT_THERE]
Driver Name: keyboard.inf
```

How do I get only these in this file;

```
CANON DR-C240 USB
Status: Started
```

When I try this command:

```
pnputil /enum-devices | findstr USB | Find /i "CANON Fijutsu"
```

...it gives the following output;

```
Device Description: CANON DR-C240 USB
```

I also want to see the `status` section, but when I add `status` in `FIND`, it also brings up the status of other equipment.

Comment: Do you know what the `|` character does, and the difference between `findstr` and `find`?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your command given your stated task. What is the reason why you cannot just use ```%SystemRoot%\System32\pnputil.exe /enum-devices /class image```, or just for connected or disconnected ones, ```%SystemRoot%\System32\pnputil.exe /enum-devices /class image /connected```, or ```%SystemRoot%\System32\pnputil.exe /enum-devices /class image /disconnected``` respectively. Alternatively omit that additional option, and pipe it, through `findstr`: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\pnputil.exe /enum-devices /class image | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^Manufacturer ^Status"```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just `findstr` over the complete command (as you noticed, it will find unrelated lines). Search for the Instance IDs first, then get the information for each of them separately, so you can easily filter for your desired information:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('pnputil /enum-devices /class Mouse ^|find "Instance ID:"') do for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%a") do call :getInfo "%%b"
goto :eof

:getinfo
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%c in ('pnputil /enum-devices /InstanceID "%~1"  ^| findstr /b "Device Status"') do for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ("%%c") do echo %%d
echo/
```

The second `for` loops (`%%b`, `%%d`) are needed to remove the trailing spaces of the second token after separating by colon.

NOTE: the search strings are language dependent (the tokens are not due to the second `for` loops instead of counting the tokens after separating them by spaces, which might seem to be the obvious solution, but for example `Device Description` (two words in English) would be `Gerätebeschreibung` (one word in German))

(judging by your example, your class is `Image` - I used `Mouse` to get a replicable output on systems without Scan-devices)

Same for direct use on command line (just in case you really need it there instead of using a readable reusable script):

```
@for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %a in ('pnputil /enum-devices /class mouse ^|find "Instance ID:"') do @(for /f "tokens=*" %b in ("%a") do @for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %c in ('pnputil /enum-devices /InstanceID "%~b"  ^| findstr /b "Device Status"') do @for /f "tokens=*" %d in ("%c") do @echo %d)&@echo\
```